Настройка эмулятора в Android Studio
Emulator Nexus 5X API 29
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Greeting()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(10.dp),
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Add Book"
            )
        }
    }
}

Выводит в эмуляторе

Должно быть так. Этот скрин взял из видеоурока.


Вот - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpAQ7nluG-g
